# Is it possible to do this in Regex

Tags: c#, regex

This is the required format to be checked:

`{low limit} - {high limit}Volts`

Or

`{low limit} to {high limit}Volts`

Ex:

```
50 - 150Volts
50 to 150Volts
```

And Low Limit must be less than high limit.
Space is allowed before and after '-' or 'to'

If possible in Regex then that would be really helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to check if the string has this format. But it is **not** possible to check if the first value is lower then the second value.

This is, because the numbers are only a sequence of characters to the Regex.

However, if you aren't limited to Regex alone, you could parse the string with a Regex, putting each number in a group. Then parse the values of the groups as integers and compare them in C#.

```
(?<min>\d+) (-|to) (?<max>\d+)Volts
```

This could be your Regex, if the spaces are mandatory.

```
if (int.Parse(match.Groups["min"].Value) < int.Parse(match.Groups["max"].Value))
{
    // ok
}
```

This shows the principle of accessing the groups, parsing and comparing ...

Answer (score 0):

```
([0-9]+)[ ]?(\-|to)[ ]?([0-9]+)Volts
```

This regex matches your examples.

You can't check if low =< high in the regex, but you can use the first and third capturing group to get the values and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression should be what you need: `(\d+)(\s+(-|to)\s+)(\d+)Volts`. If spaces are mandatory and not optional in your text then you can simplify it and replace `\s+` with a space.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"(\d+)\s*(?:-|to)\s*(\d+)", delegate(Match m)
{
    // ... check also
    m.Groups[1].Value // 50
    m.Groups[2].Value // 150

    //([1] < [2])?
    ...
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. suggestion by Hinek is also correct.